# tkinterの×ボタン（ウインドウを閉じるボタン）と自ら作成した閉じるボタンの動きがわからない

Tags: python, csv, tkinter

目的として、GUI画からテキストボックスに入力されて値を取得して、CSVファイルに書き込みすることです。画面のソースファイル（sample_tkinter.py）とCSVに書き込むためのソースファイル（merge.py）で構成しています。
現状`word1`に値を代入するところまでできていますが、
画面の右上にある×ボタン（ウインドウを閉じるボタン）を押すと、テキストボックスの値を取得することができるのですが、こちらで作成した「閉じる」ボタンを押すと、値を取得することができません。「閉じる」ボタンを押してもCSVに書き込みがされていません。値が取得できていないのか、取得はできているが処理が途中なのかわからないので、方法を知りたいです。

**sample_tkinter.py**

```
import tkinter as tk
import sys

def finish_menu():
    sys.exit()

root=tk.Tk()
root.geometry("300x300")

entry=tk.Entry()
entry.place(x=20,y=30)

button=tk.Button(text="OK")
button.place(x=150,y=29)

word1=""    
def click():
    global word1
    word1=entry.get()
   
    label=tk.Label(text="確定しました")
    label.place(x=20,y=50)

button["command"]=click

Label_Blanc = tk.Label(root, text=u'')
Label_Blanc.grid(row=50,column=50)
finish_menu_Button = tk.Button(root, text=u'閉じる')
finish_menu_Button["command"] = finish_menu
finish_menu_Button.place(x=30,y=60)


root.mainloop()
```

**merge.py**

```
import csv

from sample_tkinter import word1

with open("sample.csv","w",encoding="shift-jis")as csvfile:
    writer=csv.writer(csvfile,lineterminator="\n")
    
    writer.writerow([word1])
print(word1)
```

Comment: このプログラムの起動方法と使い方を教えてください。（質問に追記してください）

Answer (score 1):

`merge.py`から`sample_tkinter.py`を呼び出した場合に`word1`の内容が表示されないのは、[`sys.exit`](https://docs.python.org/ja/3.7/library/sys.html)でPythonの処理自体を終了していることが原因です。
ご質問のコードでは`print(word1)`が実行されません。

下記のように`finish_menu`関数から`tkinter.Tk#destroy`を呼び出すよう書き換えてください。
`destroy`については、公式ドキュメントの[A Hello World Program](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/tkinter.html#a-hello-world-program)で触れられています。

```
def finish_menu():
    # sys.exit()
    root.destroy()
```

実証に使用した下記のサンプルコードも参考になるかもしれません。

**サンプルコード**

```
import tkinter as tk
import sys

root=tk.Tk()
root.geometry("300x100")

# sys.exit() を呼び出すボタン
button_exit=tk.Button(text="Exit", command=sys.exit)
button_exit.place(x=0,y=0)

# root.destroy() を呼び出すボタン
button_destroy=tk.Button(text="Destroy", command=root.destroy)
button_destroy.place(x=150,y=0)

root.mainloop()

# sys.exitした場合はmainloopでpythonを終了する
# root.destroyした場合はwindowを閉じてmainloopを終了するだけなので、下の処理も継続して実行する

print("Exitボタンでは表示されない")
```